# mkfs.vfat and mkfs.ext3 in CYGWIN

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm running a bash script in the Embedded Command Line that comes with Quartus II. The bash script was sent to me from someone using linux and I was able to get most of the script to work(removing sudo, changing path, etc.). The only two commands that are still giving me errors are `mkfs.ext3` and `mkfs.vfat`. Are these tucked away somewhere in cygwin that I need to add a path or is there another workaround? I've read some people use mkdofsf but cygwin doesn't appear to have that either.

UPDATE:

Tried using `/sbin/mkfs - t vfat` and `/sbin/mkfs -t ext3` but this left me with a similiar error where mkfs.vfat and mkfs.ext3 were not found.

UPDATE 2: Installed `e2fsprogs` to solve the error with mkfs.ext3 but this doesn't solve the vfat formatting issue.

Comment: vfat is a windows native format. You do not need a cygwin command to built it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are part of the package `e2fsprogs` which is available in Cygwin. I've never tried these commands, assuming that access to the raw devices would be blocked by Windows. But I see that `cfdisk` seems to work. It at least starts up, anyway. So, maybe it is doable.

If they don't work on raw devices, if your scripts are creating file systems on a file or can be modified to do that, that should probably work.

Anyway, `e2fsprogs` is what you need, but be careful here. Whenever you start making or editing file systems, you have the opportunity to really screw up your system. Just be attentive to what the script is doing, and don't blindly go forward.

Comment: ```e2fsprogs``` can't format using vfat that I can tell but this worked for ext3